# htaccess - rewrite only inside folder

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hava a folder - careers - and i want to do the rewrite only for the files of that folder, for example:

mydomain.com/file.html -> its out of the folder

mydomain.com/folerone/file.html -> its out of the folder

mydomain.com/careers/ -> this calls the file index.php

mydomain.com/careers/item -> this calls the file index.php with the $_GET variable item

mydomain.com/careers/item2 -> this calls the file index.php with the $_GET variable item2

My actual .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+) index.php?itemid=$1 [QSA]
```

This is not working.. can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the .htaccess file inside the careers folder

`RewriteRule item([0-9]*)?$ index.php?itemid=item$1 [QSA]`

Comment: Yes, i have the .htaccess inside the folder.

Comment: @rennyrocha don't edit the question after someone already answered, i edited my solution

Comment: Ok @fiction, i edited because other users could misunderstood my problem.. Thank you for the answer, that didn't work..
however, with this it worked!
`RewriteRule item([0-9]*)?$ /index.php?itemid=item$1 [QSA]`