# Show the link as if it was linked to the file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

can we show the url like this using htaccess

```
http://www.example.com/group/goroupName
```

I have `group.php` file in the `pages` ***folder***. I want to show the url like above.

I have tryed it like this rule

```
RewriteRule ^group/([\w-]+)/?$ pages/group.php?group_username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but some included php files not displayed. For example :

```
<?php 
    include_once '../../functions/includes.php';
   if(isset($_GET['group_username'])) {
    $group_username=$_GET['group_username'];
    include_once '../../functions/includes/get_group.php';  
    if(empty($group_profile_owner_id)){
      header("Location:$url404");
    }
   }else{
      header("Location:$url404");
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#8e24aa">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title><?php echo $group_username;?></title>
<?php include("../../themes/$getTemplate/contents/style_js.php");?>
</head>

<body>
```

in the above code this include not displayed:

```
<?php include("../../themes/$getTemplate/contents/style_js.php");?>
```

What is the problem in my `RewriteRule`

Comment: Could you please provide some more informations, about what are the non displayed files ? If i understood you problem you can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138555/htaccess-rewrite-only-inside-folder)

Comment: @CharfiOmar Thank you for your answer. I just added example which file not displayed.

Comment: @anubhava I have really tryed but almost same problem on that time.

Comment: @anubhava because of it is global file all `css`, `js` file is in the `style_js.php` file i just write an example here with `style.css`

Comment: @anubhava Dear i have added some other code in the question maybe it will be better to give a solution

Comment: @anubhava `http://localhost:8888/themes/themeName/contents/style_js.php`

Comment: @anubhava Now it is working, so that means my `RewriteRule` is correct right ?

Comment: @anubhava Dear can i ask you a mini question from here or chat section please ?

Comment: @anubhava This is my php switch case in the index.php file `if(isset($_GET['pages'])){
 $pages = $_GET['pages'];  
}   
 switch ($pages) {  
   case 'dashboard':
   include('sources/dashboard.php');
   break;
   case 'wellcome':
   include('sources/wellcome.php'); 
   break;  
   case 'forgot_password':
   include('sources/forgot_password.php');
   break; 
   case 'groups':
   include('sources/groups.php');
   break;  
 }` you can see the sources/groups.php the link is http://localhost:8888/groups.php now can i show the groups.php using htaccess ? because i get 404 pagenotfound

Comment: @anubhava I have tryed this RewriteRule but still getting 404 `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava but if i use my RewriteRule code like this : `RewriteRule (?:^|/)([\w-]+)/?$ sources/user_profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [L,QSA]` then i get sources/user_profile.php but i get an empty page from sources/goups.php and if i change the codes like this : `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pages=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)([\w-]+)/?$ sources/user_profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]` then i see profile but i get 404 error from groups.php

Comment: @anubhava If possible can you check me htaccess code for me please ?

Comment: @anubhava [here is my htaccess codes](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/mLNbjK)

Comment: @anubhava I don't understand, can you explain me dear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171803/discussion-between-anubhava-and-azzo).

Comment: @anubhava So, what should i do to short it, can you help me about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` is correct and should work.

Problem is with `include` function in `PHP` where you're using a relative path. Due to URL rewrite this relative path changes.

You are better off using a relative path from `DOCUMENT_ROOT` as:

```
<?php
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/themes/themeName/contents/style_js.php');
?>
```